# SQL Server expecting different date format

Tags: sql-server, asp-classic, localization

I have set the SQL Server's default language to "British". The following correctly returns 23...

```
sp_configure 'default language'
```

I have also set the language of my login to "British" too with...

```
 sp_defaultlanguage @loginame = 'Login123', @language = 'British'
```

However, when I attempt to specify `13/12/2015` as a DateTime stored procedure parameter from ASP Classic, I get...

> Error converting data type nvarchar to datetime.

From Management Studio, with the correct login, it works.

Why would ASP Classic have this effect? I'm pretty sure it's using the correct connection string.

**EDIT:**

Its not the connection string. Somehow the date's format is being converted incorrectly before being sent to the database. I can see this from Profiler.

Comment: That should work, as far as I can tell. Do you have a fuller example?

Comment: I've updated the question.

Comment: Is the ASP classic using the same username to log in to the server? It may also be affected by the language settings in IIS, from what I remember...

Comment: I've set the LCID in IIS to 2057. "Date()", for example, has the correct format.

Comment: If I disable the login, it won't let me log in at all. So, it must be using the correct login.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`CONVERT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) with style:

> British/French
>
> 103 = dd/mm/yyyy

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, '13/12/2015', 103);

-- with stored procedure
DECLARE @d DATETIME = CONVERT(DATETIME, '13/12/2015', 103);

EXEC [dbo].[my_stored_procedure] @d;
```

---

Another method is to use [`ISO 8601`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190977%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) date literal which is culture independent:

> **The advantage in using the ISO 8601 format is that it is an international standard. Also, datetime values that are specified by using this format are unambiguous.** Also, this format is not affected by the SET DATEFORMAT or SET LANGUAGE settings.
>
> yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss[.mmm]

```
EXEC [dbo].[my_stored_procedure] '2015-12-13T00:00:00'
```

Comment: Actually, I've realised what I'm doing does work, except when from my app. Perhaps IIS is overriding something.

Comment: @IanWarburton Consider using ISO8601 and your life will be much easier.

Comment: I've inherited an old, large ASP Classic project. ;)