# ADO Classic changes the format of a date type query parameter

Tags: asp-classic, ado

```
Set cmd = Server.CreateObject("adodb.command")
cmd.CommandText = "sp"
cmd.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@starttime", adVarChar, adParamInput, 120)
cmd("@starttime") = CDate(trim(dateadd("d",daynumber,startday)))
```

The following outputs, "13/12/2015".

```
Response.Write CDate(trim(dateadd("d",daynumber,startday)))
```

The following outputs,  "12/13/2015", which ultimately appears in the generated SQL string.

```
Response.Write cmd("@starttime")
```

How do I stop ADO from changing the date format?

Comment: Where is `startday` being assigned?, yet again your question lacks proper detail. What does the stored procedure do with`@date` parameter?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server expecting different date format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34243521/sql-server-expecting-different-date-format)

Comment: Why would you pass a date as `adVarChar` for anyway and mores to the point why would it be 120 characters long? If you are interested in the correct data type mappings and corresponding constant values I recommend this article - [Data Type Mapping](http://www.carlprothman.net/Technology/DataTypeMapping/tabid/97/Default.aspx)

Comment: @Lankymart I don't think either of the details you're requesting are relevant. What does it matter where startdate is assigned? And what does it matter what the stored procedure does with the value? The problem is the conversion of the format.

Comment: @Lankymart Regarding adVarChar, I've inherited the code. I don't know what it does. However, I do know that this code worked on the environment it came from. i.e. its a config issue.

Comment: Incidentally, many of the ridiculously long questions on here I don't bother to read. I read the title, the first sentence and head for the answers. :)

Comment: And with that comment I'm out of here, work it out yourself. That attitude just shows a huge amount of disrespect for those who have spent their time writing a detailed answer in a bid to try and help you and others.

Comment: @Lankymart Aha... I apologize, `@date` was simply a typo. It should have been `@starttime`.

Comment: @Lankymart I am very sorry for my disrespect. I appreciate your time and effort in helping me.

Comment: @Lankymart You hit on a solution anyway. See answer.

Answer (score 1):

I gave up trying to get the config right and changed the code by changing the type of the parameter to `adDBTimeStamp`, which is obviously what it should have been all along. Any other instances of this I will have to change similarly.

```
cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@starttime", adDBTimeStamp, adParamInput)
```

Comment: You are unbelievable, I give you a link to the correct constant data type mappings and you still get it wrong, it should be `adDBTimeStamp` to map correctly to `datetime`.

Comment: Corrected!! Thanks. :) Why don't you write much the same answer and I will tick it.